# implicit declaration of function ‘atoi’?

Tags: c, atoi

Why am I getting an error when using the `atoi()` function?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char s1[10], s2[10];
    int x=5, y=6, z;
    sprintf(s1, "%d", x);
    sprintf(s2, "%d", y);
    strcat(s1, s2);
    z = atoi(s1);
    printf("%d, %s", z, s1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since `atoi()` is declared in `<stdlib.h>`, as `man atoi` would tell you, it is a reasonable error (and it should, indeed, be treated as an error, not just a warning).

Comment: Aside: for a 32-bit `int` the `char s1[10],s2[10];` arrays are too small to be safe over the whole range of values. There can be 10 digits, a minus sign, and a string terminator, total 12. So define them as `char s1[16], s2[16];` and don't be tight.

Comment: Then how is atoi() without including stdlib.h compiles and runs? Can anyone explain ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Will fix it.